# Swagger UI does not display operationId

Tags: c#, swagger, swagger-ui

Our C# Asp.NET (not core) REST API uses the Swashbuckle nuget package (thanks Richard Morris) v5.6 to generate the swagger definition and UI page. The problem is, that the **operationId** is not displayed on the UI page.

I can see on several pages that the .net core version contains a mystic **DisplayOperationId=true** configuration settings to (hopelessly) solve this issue. But in the non .net core version I cannot find this settings, nor cannot see a working example how to customize the UI to display that piece of information.

Could somebody help me how to solve this problem? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the query args `&displayOperationId=true` in url may useful.

test:
https://petstore.swagger.io/?displayOperationId=1

ref:
https://swagger.io/docs/open-source-tools/swagger-ui/usage/configuration/#displayOperationId

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs...

> displayOperationId    DISPLAY_OPERATION_ID    Boolean=false. Controls the
>   display of operationId in operations list. The default is false.

https://swagger.io/docs/open-source-tools/swagger-ui/usage/configuration/

Comment: That doc says there are 4 ways to do that. I tried adding to the URL (4th) as http://localhost/myapp/swagger/ui/index?DISPLAY_OPERATION_ID=true but won't work. The 3rd I cannot understand (specified configUrl ??). The 2nd - cannot find the way, where to pass that object (an example should help). The 1st - I added the swagger-config.yaml file to my project (to the same folder where the .csproj is) with the content displayOperationId: true but it also won't helped :( Now I am sad but curious ...

Comment: @ZoltanHernyak If you are using index.html then "displayOperationId: true" should be added to the "const ui = SwaggerUIBundle({})" yaml data.